# Get Qubole data row wise using java

Tags: java, hive, qubole

Am trying to run a `hive` query using [Qubole SDK](https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-java). Though am able to get the desired result as `string`, in order to better process it, am looking to access this row-wise. Something like a list of java objects.

The way am getting the data is:

```
CommandResponse commandResponse = client.command().hive().query(query).invoke().get();
ResultLatch resultLatch = new ResultLatch(client, commandResponse.getId());
ResultValue resultValue = resultLatch.awaitResult();
System.out.println(resultValue.getResults());
```

And the console gives an output like:

```
"val1"  "val2"  "val3"  "val4"
........ some more set of values .......
```

I was looking to have this result set in the form of list which I can iterate over instead of parsing or tokenizing the bunch of strings.

Unable to find any library or class if its there.

Answer (score 0):

Split string by `\r\n` first, then by `\t` like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

...

private static String convertNulls(String s) {
    \\Use this function to convert blanks, null and \\N to''
    return StringUtils.isBlank(s) | 
       s.equalsIgnoreCase("null") | 
        s.equalsIgnoreCase("\\N") ? "" : s;
}

...

inputStr=resultValue.getResults();

if (!StringUtils.isBlank(inputStr)) {
            for (String row: inputStr.split("\r\n")) { //split rows
                String[] s = row.split("\t");          //split columns

                //Do what you want here with s 
                //Use convertNulls method to convert all NULLs variations to empty strings
                //Or load some ArrayList or Map, etc


            }
```